# Digital signature in pdf file using reactJs

Tags: reactjs, digital-signature

I need to build an app that accepts pdf file from the user and place an image of a user image signature (which is already uploaded by the user) where a user clicks on pdf.
same as Adobe reader provide a feature to add the digital signature.
I am using ReactJs to build this app.

Anyone know any clue how to do this.

I am trying some library to read pdf but they are not providing the feature of editing.

Anyone know any npm which spot Reacts??

Answer (score 0):

Digital signature needs private key of the user. To digitally sign via your web application, users would need to allow your application access to their private key. Since your application is a **web** application, there is no guarantee for users that it will not send private key to your back end or somewhere else. That is why all users that have some understanding of security will refuse to use your web application for digital signature.

Your use case is not clear. What do you want to achieve with that? Consider following alternative. You can use your own private key for signature. If user is registered, you can add a text to the document, that you confirm that user X signed this document and sign it with **your own** private key.

Comment: i am working in a company and this is my company project.

I don't need to take tension of user privacy. User privacy is company headache. I just need to implement this functionality

Comment: Don't you want to explain your company that this makes no sense and that reasonable users will not use it because this is **dangerous** from the **security** perspective? Thus you would show that you care about the company's reputation.

Comment: This app is for some specific user not for everyone. So, There is no such case as you mentioned.